# Rsync shows error(s) but the files were successfully copied

Tags: permissions, rsync

The host machine is running on Centos7
My pc is running on Ubuntu 20.04

I'm transferring images operationally using rsync from the Centos7 to Ubuntu using this command:

```
rsync -auvz ${src_d01_pcp_1hr}/ francis@192.168.60.250:${dest_d01_pcp_1hr}/
```

I'm getting this error:

```
rsync: chgrp "/var/www/html/pywrf_output/d01/pcp_1hr/." failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

but when I check my filemanager in ubuntu my files are there successfully transferred.

also

at the beginning of my shell script. the script deletes the previous images to make room for the new ones and I'm using this:

```
ssh -t -t francis@192.168.xx.xxx "rm -rf ${pywrf_dest_nmsis}/d01/*/*.png"
```

I get this error for some reason but still the operation proceeds

```
Connection to 192.168.60.250 closed.
```

Are there any possible workaround for this?

EDIT:
the host machine is not mine. Its from my co worker.

Comment: The error indicates that the group can't be set on the target directory, because you don't have permissions to change this. Presumably, the group ownership is different on the target compare to the source. This is not an answer as there was no actual question.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you! I really don't know what to ask because I just started using shell scripts last week and I was tinkering with it. And I was just curious because there was this error but the outcome that I wanted happens.